# Variables in vb script

Tags: string, variables, vbscript

I have create a vb script which takes contents of text file (C:\textfile.txt) and writes it to windows event log. I have an issue of variable "strContents" which suppose to "pull" text from C:\textfile.txt Does anyone knows how to write this variable?

Thanks a lot.

```vb
    CONST INFORMATION = 4
    Const ForReading = 1

    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\textfile.txt", ForReading)
      strContents = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close


    wscript.echo strContents
    strCommand = "eventcreate /T Information /ID 100 /L Application /SO                 eventlog /D " "strContents"
    WshShell.Run strcommand
```

Comment: Please exclude [vbs] in prevous posting.

Comment: What is `[vbs]`? And why can't you just assign to the variable? You know, `strContents = ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
strCommand = "eventcreate /T Information /ID 100 /L Application /SO eventlog /D """ & strContents & """"
'                                                                                ^  ^             ^  ^
' This becomes one double quote -------------------------------------------------+  |             |  |
' This is the string concatenation operator ----------------------------------------+             |  |
' This is the string concatenation operator ------------------------------------------------------+  |
' This becomes one double quote ---------------------------------------------------------------------+

' Another way to execute "command-line" commands
' that displays errors and output of the command

dim WSE
set WSE = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
WScript.Echo "======== STDERR ========"
do until WSE.StdErr.AtEndOfStream
    WScript.Echo WSE.StdErr.ReadLine
loop
WScript.Echo "======== STDOUT ========"
do until WSE.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    WScript.Echo WSE.StdOut.ReadLine
loop
```

Comment: Hi again, I have chenged in my code, but it doesn´t write values from text, only this is written in event log: strContents

Comment: Hi again, I have chenged in my code, but it doesn´t write values from text, only this is written in event log: strContents

Comment: Can you post what gets printed when you do a `wscript.echo strCommand`? I think you should enclose the string after `/D` parameter inside double quotes (see edited answer)

Comment: Thanks for answers... What I get by wscript.echo strCommand is pop up message, did it just for checking whether it pulls text from textfile.txt, and this is succesfull. But if i write this: /D """ & strContents & """" to my code, it doesn´t do anything, no expected entries in eventlog??

Comment: (i) if you do not get any entry at all the see revised answer (ii) if you get an entry but no description make sure the `"` match.

Comment: Thanks, just don´t get it where should I put Your part of code, should I use eventcreate utility?

Comment: The revised code from `WshShell.Exec ...` should be used instead of `WshShell.Run ...`. The run command (I think) does not allow you to capture stdout/stderr, the exec command does; this will allow you to read errors returned by `eventcreate` command.